# how do you escape a hyphen/dash in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert a date `2013-3-17` but it's treating it as a mathematical operation and inserting 1993. How do I escape the hyphen?

Comment: You don't escape the hyphens, you quote the whole thing `'2013-03-17'` (and the month has a leading zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `date` data type. You also need to wrap your date in quotes.

Comment: Even with a date type, it has to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround literal dates with quotation marks, either `"2013-03-17"` or `'2013-03-17'`

Comment: I assure you, you can use either kind.

Comment: Sorry, *unless you turn on ANSI_QUOTES*, then you're forced to use single quotes.